# AWS Step Function itemsPath potentially empty

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, parallel-processing, aws-step-functions

I have a `Parallel` state with four branches.  Each branch is represented by a `Map` state.

I chunk my array into sub-arrays of 250 items in a lambda, return it, and pass it to `itemsPath` via Step Function context like:

`itemsPath: '$.props0'`

There is every chance sometimes one to three of my 4 sub-arrays will be empty, this is causing a number of branches in my SF to fail with below error:

`Unable to apply step \"props1\" to input`

Is there any way to make `itemsPath` optional?  Or only run a `Map` state if `itemsPath` is not empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accounted for this in my lambda, then leveraged a `Condition` inside a `Choice`, and called the appropriate `State` - either a single `Map`, or my four nested `Map`s in my `Parallel`.